# Как вывести список файлов по маске php

Tags: php

не получаеться, подскажите.

```
$dir = "./file";   //задаём имя директории
    if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
         //echo $dir.' - директория существует;<br>';
         $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) {

         if(preg_match("~ext-(.*?).txt~", $files, $files)) {
         echo '-файл: <a href="'.$dir."/".$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  //выводим все файлы
        }
        }
         }

    else { echo $dir.' -такой директории нет;<br>'; }
```

мне нужна именно маска ext-(.*?).txt просто там куча текстовиков.

Comment: зачем у вас так всё сложно в условии, наверное надо было:

    if (if(preg_match("~ext-.*\.txt~", $files[$i])) {

Comment: через два оператора? или просто прег_мач изменить?

Answer (score 2):

знаю вопрос задан давно, но вдруг кто наткнется есть такое решение:

```
foreach (glob("$somePath/file*.doc") as $docFile) {
   // .....
}
```